# yaml in Google App Engine with index.html

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm building a website, I have no index.py how to I ensure index.html comes up when I type in my http://localhost:8080/?

I have in yaml

```
- url: /
  static_files: static/HTML
  upload: static/HTML/index.html
```

but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `static_files` directive needs to include the full path to the file:

```
static_files: static/HTML/index.html
```